# What process did Indian Government use to remove high value currency notes out of circulation?

Tags: india, currency

So the day before US election, Narendra Modi dropped a bomb that 500 and 1000 INR notes will be dropped from circulation. I want to know the democratic/legal processes that let him do this.

Answer (score 7):

There is a law available for this. Under the  **Reserve Bank of
India Act, 1934 (2 of 1934) sub-section(2)**  Central Government has a powers to take back the legal status of a particular currency. This is what above section says:

> (2) On recommendation of the Central Board the 6[Central Government] may,
>   by notification in the Gazette of India, declare that, with effect from such date
>   as may be specified in the notification, any series of bank notes of any
>   denomination shall cease to be legal tender 7[save at such office or agency of
>   the Bank and to such extent as may be specified in the notification]

So Modi has used above powers to remove legal status of high value currency notes. You can read more information from official notification by [RBI](https://rbi.org.in/Scripts/BS_PressReleaseDisplay.aspx?prid=38520) and official notification from [Ministry Of Finance](http://finmin.nic.in/172521.pdf) also you can see the corresponding act in below [link.](https://rbidocs.rbi.org.in/rdocs/Publications/PDFs/RBIAM_230609.pdf)